# Difference size vs track_total_hits in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

size in elasticsearch query means no. of documents we want to fetch.
track_total_hits is what ? Both are doing same task if we set track_total_hits 10 and size is 10 then i am getting 10 result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `size: 10` you're asking how many hits you want in the results.

With `track_total_hits:...`

- `true` you're telling ES that you're interested to know how many total hits your query could return
- `false` you're telling ES that you're **not** interested to know how many total hits your query could return

Settings `track_total_hits: false` is an optimization to prevent ES from having to count all hits if you're only interested in the first N results and are not interested in the total hit count.

Comment: Let suppose we are specifying size=10 and track_total_hits=10 , then how many records i will get.

Comment: You will get 10 records, since size is asking for 10 max